# Solution.metaproj error MSB3202: The project file 'xxx' was not found

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a TFS Project with two main folders:

Project

--Folder1

----LibraryA

--Folder2

----AppA referencing LibraryA

When I build AppA solution, TFS fails to build, providing the following Error:

C:\Builds\1\Project\AppA\Sources\Folder2..\Folder1\LibraryA\LibraryA.csproj

I think TFS is doing something like $(CurrentBuildDir)$(ProjectReferenceSourceLocation), which just sticks the ..\Folder1\LibraryA part on there.

I know shared assemblies should probably be build in their own solution and then references made to the build copies but this is how it is.

Any ideas how to get TFS to know how to navigate out of the solution folder to find referenced projects?

TIA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible pitfall here is that you haven't set the source control path under `$/Project1/Folder1/LibraryA` as an active Working folder in the Workspace tab of your build definition.
If that's the case, sources won't be downloaded to the build-Agent during Build & naturally the compile is going to fail complaining about missing sources.

Comment: That's right. You'll want to make sure that any dependencies are mapped into your build definition's workspace to the same relative locations as in your development environment.

Comment: Not only possible but the actual problem.  Excellent, thanks.