# TFS build failing. Unresolved references to files that are in source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, tfs

I have a build that works fine locally, however, will not build within our TFS environment.

I get the following error;

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1578): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "Assembly.Services.Common". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

The assembly in question is checked into TFS and is in the following location;

> /Root/BaseBinRefs/Assembly.Services.Common.dll

It does not have any external references outside of the .net framework.

The project that is failing to build is in the following location in TFS

> /Root/Services/AssemblySolutionFolder/AssemblyThatIsFailing

The assembly is referenced in a project within the solution and the HintPath to the assembly appear to be correct;

```
   <Reference Include="Assembly.Services.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, 
      Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\BaseBinRefs\Assembly.Services.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

As said, it builds locally and I can see no reason why it should fail within TFS. the caveat to that is that I am new to TFS in general and still trying to integrate the first of our projects into this environment.

**Update 1**

Using ProcessMonitor, I see TFS attempting to load the file from;

C:\Builds\1\Root\BaseBinRefs\Assembly.Services.Common.dll

Which does not exist, but is correct in the relative sense. Now, when I look in the Sources directory, I see BaseBinRefs, with Assembly.Services.Common.dll included, so it has downloaded them (I added the BaseBinRefs to the build definition)

Comment: *Could not locate the assembly* - using ProcessMonitor on the server when you kick off a build, can you tell us where is it looking for `Assembly.Services.Common.dll`?

Comment: Check here for a possible resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592277/solution-metaproj-error-msb3202-the-project-file-xxx-was-not-found/8592448#8592448

Comment: @pantelif Thanks. I had already made sure that was done and it does copy the files into my sources, but the build still looks in another location.

Comment: pantelif's answer looks to be on the right lines. Could you update the question with your build worspace mappings? This is almost certainly the source of the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be an issue on how the working folders are set up in your build definition (under Workspace).
If I understood your path-scheme correctly, setting the paths as follows should work:

```
Active |$/TeamProject/Root/BaseBinRefs/                    |$(SourceDir)\Root\BaseBinRefs
Active |$/TeamProject/Root/Services/AssemblySolutionFolder/|$(SourceDir)\Root\Services\AssemblySolutionFolder
```

whereas, for example, this would cause trouble:

```
Active |$/TeamProject/Root/BaseBinRefs/                    |$(SourceDir)\
Active |$/TeamProject/Root/Services/AssemblySolutionFolder/|$(SourceDir)\
```

Comment: I was just going to add use the GAC to get around this issue.

Comment: @Jeremy: In my opinion, inserting into the GAC a source-controlled assembly is not a good idea.

Comment: @pantelif As above, I already added the working folder and it is correct.

Comment: That's very interesting. Open with Visual Studio the SLN that resides under `C:\Builds\1`. I expect VS2010 to correct the ref & your solution should compile. Now take this `AssemblyThatIsFailing.csproj` and compare it to the one checked in - this might provide with a hint on the issue.

Comment: Strangely enough, the solution I implemented (temporarily) was to have a local binrefs folder and although this worked, I preferred to have the the initial problem resolved. I moved everything back and it is now all working. I am going to mark this as the correct answer is I believe it was something to do with this all along, although as   shown above, I had added the paths correctly.