# TFS Build: Referencing different version of Oracle than what's on the buyild server

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild, odp.net

The short story:  Using TFS 2010, I can't get the build server to build using the specific version of Oracle.DataAcess that I need on my target server.

We have one build server at this point for the entire enterprise which has a messy mix of Oracle, .Net, and OS versions. The project I'm building is for a server with a different version of the Oracle.DataAccess.dll than what's on the build server.  If I build it on my local machine and deploy to the dev server it works fine.  But I can't seem to get the build server to ignore it's version of the client and use mine.

I've read a couple of excellent questions and answers, such as this one answered by pantelif:
[Solution.metaproj error MSB3202: The project file 'xxx' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592277/solution-metaproj-error-msb3202-the-project-file-xxx-was-not-found/8592448#8592448)

I think I'm doing everything right.  I even include a Ref folder within my project and directly reference the .dll from there. So I'm not trying to reference a .dll from a different location.

If I set Specific Version = false, I get a runtime Oracle error telling me the version of the Oracle client is wrong.  If I manually copy the correct version of the .dll into the bin folder, I get a runtime error saying  the assembly is targetting a different version.

If I set Specific Version = true, the build server says it can't find the .dll

```
Class\ProvData.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1360): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.102.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

When I look at my project file, I see what I would expect:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.102.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342">
  <HintPath>Ref\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

So any ideas on why the build server still says it can't find it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your build server doesn't have the same version of `Oracle.DataAccess` as your dev machine.

You can try:

- Use the lib referencing pattern, where your projects referencing to a file in a specific source-controlled location:

  ```
  <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.102.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342">
    <HintPath>..\..\Lib\ODP.NET\1.102.3.0\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  ```
- Remove the FQN from its definition, (allowing the CLR to pick any matching version):

  ```
  <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess" />
  ```
- Make sure the build server has the same assembly version by deploying it the GAC using [`gacutil /i`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx):

  ```
  gacutil /i Oracle.DataAccess.dll
  ```